# Problem with StringPosition[] and slowness of Import[] in sentiment analysis

Tags: import, string-manipulation, finance

Using the post by J. Kinlay at [Market Sentiment Analysis](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/970999) we can employ a simple yet effective Mathematica implementation for sentiment analysis in trading.

Everything is very clear and useful in the post. However, now when I just use the `Import[]` and `StringPosition[]`, they are slow and print warning issues due to extracting [[1,2]] position from nothing as follows:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

tsopen1 = 
 TimeSeries[
  FinancialData["NYSE:MMM", 
   "Open", {{2017, 1, 1}, {2020, 05, 09}, "Day"}]]
tsclose1 = 
 TimeSeries[
  FinancialData["NYSE:MMM", 
   "Close", {{2017, 1, 1}, {2020, 05, 09}, "Day"}]]
tsreturns1 = (tsclose1 - tsopen1)/tsopen1;
pl3 = DateListPlot[tsreturns1, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
   ImageSize -> 400, PlotStyle -> Gray,
   PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> Style["3M Co. intraday returns."], 
   PlotLegends -> Placed["Intraday returns", {Right, Top}]];

datelist = tsopen1["Dates"];
```

But now when we use the following lines, we face with some errors:

```
    archive1 = Import[StringJoin["http://www.wsj.com/public/page/archive-",
    DateString[
     datelist[[1]], {"Year", "-", "MonthShort", "-", "DayShort"}], 
    ".html"]];
archive2 = StringDrop[archive1, StringPosition[archive1,
     DateString[
      datelist[[1]], {"MonthName", " ", "DayShort", ", ", 
       "Year"}]][[1, 2]]];
archive3 = 
  StringTake[
   archive1, -1 + StringPosition[archive1, "ARCHIVE FILTER"][[1, 1]]];
archivewords = ToLowerCase[DeleteStopwords[TextWords[archive3]]]
TakeLargest[Counts[archivewords], 20]
WordCloud[archivewords]
```

Can anyone put some comments that why `DateString[
    datelist[[1]], {"MonthName", " ", "DayShort", ", ", "Year"}]][[1, 
   2]]]` gives some errors and how we can speed up the process of reading from different websites faster than this? Can compiling help?

EDIT:

This is an edited version when I implemented the guides of Rohit to remove the warning issues.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
tsopen1 = 
 TimeSeries[
  FinancialData["NYSE:MMM", 
   "Open", {{2020, 01, 01}, {2020, 05, 12}, "Day"}]]
tsclose1 = 
 TimeSeries[
  FinancialData["NYSE:MMM", 
   "Close", {{2020, 01, 01}, {2020, 05, 12}, "Day"}]]
tsreturns1 = (tsclose1 - tsopen1)/tsopen1

datelistoriginal = tsopen1["Dates"];
Length[datelistoriginal]

ndays = Length[datelistoriginal]
a1 = Take[datelistoriginal, ndays];
a2 = Table[a1[[i, 1]], {i, ndays}];
a3 = Table[Take[a2[[i]], 3], {i, Length[a2]}];
a3 // Short
datelistFinal = Map[DateObject, a3];

wsjArchiveText[session_, date_] := 
 Module[{archiveDiv}, 
  WebExecute[
   session, {"OpenPage" -> 
     "https://www.wsj.com/news/archive/" <> date}];
  archiveDiv = 
   WebExecute[session, 
     "LocateElements" -> "CSSSelector" -> "#main > div > div > ol"] //
     First;
  <|date -> WebExecute[session, "ElementText" -> archiveDiv]|>]

WSJSentimentIndicator3[date_] := 
 Module[{d = date, archive, archivewords, WSJSI, data},
  session = StartWebSession[];
  data = wsjArchiveText[session, 
     DateString[d, {"Year", "Month", "Day"}]] // Association;
  DeleteObject[session];
  archive = data[DateString[d, {"Year", "Month", "Day"}]];
  archivewords = ToLowerCase[DeleteStopwords[TextWords[archive]]];
  WSJSI = #Positive/(#Negative + #Positive) &@
     Counts[Classify["Sentiment", archivewords]] // N;
  {WSJSI, archivewords, archive}]


WSJSI = ParallelTable[First@WSJSentimentIndicator3[
      datelistFinal[[i]]
      ]
    , {i, Length[datelistFinal]}]; // AbsoluteTiming
WSJSI
```

Here I limited the range of `FinancialData` to the most new ones (we have 90 trading days now). But when we call the function `WSJSentimentIndicator3[]` inside the `Table` (or even outside), we get warning issues due to web page loading and similar stuff (it seems, it can open for some days and cannot open some)! For another run, some other ones would be open and; some once again fail!

Comment: Someone else had problems with that code. See the changes I posted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1710931).

Comment: Thanks Rohit. It helped. But as mentioned in your sent link, the process is tedious due to the problem of multiple running to get the final answers! Do you have any suggestions now to remove the running errors? We need to run more than 5 times to finally get the results. The process is slow itself, let alone repeating it for several times!

Comment: I would separate the data collection from the analysis. If collection fails for one or more days you just need to try those days again. When you have a complete dataset, run the sentiment analysis.

Comment: How do you do this?
Can you please update my or your code?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any way to speed up the process of getting the data. The WSJ archive site takes a long time to load because of the ads and other unrelated content on the page. The errors can be avoided by using `WebExecute` which will wait for the page to fully load before proceeding.

```
wsjArchiveText[session_, date_] := Module[{archiveDiv},
  WebExecute[session, {"OpenPage" -> "https://www.wsj.com/news/archive/" <> date}];
  archiveDiv = 
   WebExecute[session, "LocateElements" -> "CSSSelector" -> "#main > div > div > ol"] // First;
  <|date -> WebExecute[session, "ElementText" -> archiveDiv]|>]

dates = {"20120105", "20120106"};
session = StartWebSession[];

data = (wsjArchiveText[session, #] & /@ dates) // Association;

DeleteObject[session]

data["20120106"]
(* Archive text for 20120106 *)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Rohit. Although this implementation has much better than before with fewer warning issues, when we use it in a loop (I mean to compute it for many days, e.g., 2 months), some of the data could be be loaded or something, and we still face with some errors (warning issues!) Do you have any further comments?

Comment: @Fazlollah I need more details. Are the warnings/errors from the code above or some other code? What exactly are the warnings/errors?

Comment: it seems some of the web pages still have problems to be opened properly. See the edited question above please. Maybe it is also related to the Internet connection quality!